# How can I add units to my legend using base plot?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am wondering how I can add units to my legend here? I would like to add '%' after each number on the legend. I am using base plot in R. There seems to be many solutions for ggplot2, but I can't seem to find this answer for base plot.

My code thus far:

```
plot(heat_all_rast, col = topo.colors(70))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you edit this question to make it reproducible?

Comment: Possible reproducible example: `library(raster); f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"); r <- raster(f); plot(r, col = topo.colors(70))`

Comment: using `legend` function could work. But without reproducible  example its hard to say

Comment: This seems hard since the `plot()` method for `raster` objects (which is what you seem to be doing) is not very customizable. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813101/controlling-legend-and-colors-for-raster-values-in-r) shows how to plot a raster in `ggplot`, where the color bar would be easier to customize.